# Initialization error misunderstanding... Need some clarification

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, initialization

So I have a linked list set up like this:

```
#define MAX 20
//structure for a single linked list
typedef struct element {
    int info;
    struct element *link;
} Tnode;

//structure for a grapgh
typedef struct graphAdjList {
    int nodes;
    Tnode *adjList[MAX];
} Tgraph;
```

In my code I have it set up like this:

```
Tgraph *graph;

graph = (Tgraph*) malloc(sizeof(Tgraph));
graph -> nodes = 0;

for(i; i < 20; i++){

    graph->adjList[i]= NULL;
}

graph->adjList[2]->info = 222;
```

Now if I compile this I get an access violation on this last line. Is it that I have not reserved memory for the Tnode part of the struct or am I missing something. How can I initialize the array so that I can assign a value to info in any element of the array?

Thank you

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the issue is that you have not allocated memory for the individual nodes in `adjList`.

When you do `graph->adjList[2]->info = 222;`, `graph->adjList[2]` is still `NULL` from the `for` loop right before it.

To fix this, you need to first allocate memory for it like so:

```
graph->adjList[2] = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
```

Note: You *could* just replace `graph->adjList[i] = NULL;` with `graph->adjList[i] = malloc(sizeof(Tnode));` in the for loop, but allocating as you go can be useful for memory efficiency.

Comment: Alright so if I have                                           Tnode *newnode, *tail = NULL, *head = NULL ;                     and then                                                      newnode = (Tnode*) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
   newnode->info = 1;
   newnode->link = NULL;
   graph->adjList[k]->link = newnode;                                                             would this set up the link list properly?

Comment: Assuming memory is allocated for `graph->adjList[k]`, then that will at least avoid issues involving not allocating memory. Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`; casting can hide other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

graph->adjList[i]= NULL;

to

graph->adjList[i] = (Tnode*)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));